# Custom display for constructed functions

Tags: function-construction, display

In a similar vein to my previous question, is it possible to define a function that displays differently to its default? *eg* I would really like `Binomial[a,b]` to be displayed as $a \choose b$, but still function as normal during calculation. I tried `binom[a_, b_] := Binomial[a, b]//MatrixForm` but that didn't work.

*eg* If I enter `binom[a,b]`, I would like it to display as `MatrixForm[{a,b}]`, but when I type in `With[{a=10,b=5},binom[a,b]]` I would like the output `252`.

Comment: `Interpretation[ ]`?

Comment: Are you aware of `TraditionalForm`?

Comment: @YvesKlett yes, but it doesn't evaluate the same, does it?

Comment: not foolprof, no, and just like `MatrixForm` an eternal source of confusion.

Comment: @belisarius I tried `binom[a_, b_] := Interpretation[MatrixForm[{a, b}], Binomial[a, b]]` and then `Evaluate@%` but remained unevaluated - I think I am not fully understanding...

Comment: Check [this tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningOutputFormats.html).

Comment: Perhaps you could also add a specific example showing your desired in/output.

Comment: @Karsten display is ok in that tutorial, but can't get it to evaluate as per `Binomial[a,b]` when desired.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Format[binom[a_, b_]] := TraditionalForm@Binomial[a, b]
```

Now

```
binom[a, b]
```

> $a \choose b$

and

```
With[{a = 10, b = 5}, binom[a, b]]
```

> ```
> 252
> ```

Comment: perfect - thank you!